Authorize cross region materialized view replicas
I am accessing Data Cloud objects as datasets in Google BigQuery by creating a data share (Working with Salesforce Data Cloud in BigQuery). The views are created in the aws-us-east-1 region. I have also created materialized views in the same region but in a different dataset.
To migrate this to the US region and grant access to users for the new dataset in the US region, I created materialized view replicas in US region using the following template:
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW `myproject.bq_dataset.mv_replica`
OPTIONS(
  replication_interval_seconds=600
)
AS REPLICA OF `myproject.s3_dataset.my_s3_mv`

However, when trying to authorize the new materialized views so that users can access only the dataset containing the materialized view replicas, I encounter the following error (likely due to the different regions):
View project_id:mv_replica.my_view to authorize not found.

Is there a more effective way to manage this?
We don't want to persist the data in the form of tables, hence sticking to materialized views.

Hi @Akhil, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

Hi @Ahkil, I'm facing a similar issue.  Did you manage to resolve this?
Or have a Google issue open that we can monitor?
